# How to pass Parameters from a pop-up submit to a refreshing iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, popup

How can I pass data from a pop-up with capture Photo and pass it to an iframe that reloads when the Capture photo pop-up is closed?

This is the scenario:

I have a page with an iframe that opens up a pop-up for capture photo. All I want is for the captured photo to be transferred to the parent iframe, so that when I save the form of the page where the iframe is, I can save the captured photo at the same time.

Heres my code:

**In my iframe:**

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="CarImage" id="CarImage" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a class="linkCaptureOpener button_back button_example_small" href="@Url.Action("CapturePhoto", "Vehicle", new { area = "Homeowner" , id = userId })">
            Take a Photo
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my saving event for the capture photo where I convert the image. With this, I was trying to pass the image using `RedirectToAction` as a parameter, but it only opens the iframe inside the pop-up.

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult CapturePhoto(VehicleViewModel model, string imageConverted,int id) {

    try {
        byte[] dataImage;
        string fileName = string.Empty;

        DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/CreateImage"));
        if (!dir2.Exists) {
            dir2.Create();
        }

        fileName = "CARIMAGE" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") + ".jpg";
        string fileNameWitPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CreateImage"), fileName);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create)) {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs)) {
                dataImage = Convert.FromBase64String(imageConverted);
                bw.Write(dataImage);
                bw.Close();
            }
            fs.Close();
        }

        var checkData = dataImage;

        return RedirectToAction("GetCarImage", new {filename = fileName });

    } /*END try*/

    catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    return View(model);
} /*END CapturePhoto*/
```